How to ensure tile lines stay consistent when tiling around a window
I'm tiling a new basement bathroom. 4x4" square tiles in a grid layout up most of the wall's height. Roughly in the middle of a 12' wall, I have a window.
I've not done tile around windows or doors before and it's important to me that the lines fall in the right place.
In this photo, you can see the width of the window opening matches the width of whole tiles. At least it's been trimmed up as such and looks great.

1.) How does one plan an opening that matches the width of full tiles? Are you simply adding the exact width of each tile plus an affordance for grout? If I'm using 1/8" spacers and 4" square tile, is it actually just a matter of adding those up?
2.) I'd like the corner a few feet to the right of the window to begin with a full tile and my window opening to fall exactly on the line. What I mean is that at no point am I cutting any tile until possibly when I reach the corner to the left of the window. Would this follow the same process as #1?

I realize I'm way out of my comfort zone here and not using all the right language. Thanks so much for your time!

Measure the tiles first.  Most tiles/wood are sold by nominal size, not actual size.  Then measure, measure, measure.  Also start with a level line, do not just go by floor level.

You'll need some real good luck if you want the edge of a full tile to end up at the window casing like in your sketch!

Your desires and planning are all based on the premise that the walls are perfectly plumb and square to the floor as well as the window frame being perfectly plumb and perfectly parallel with the side walls.  That never happens.
To minimise the chance that the tile may be stacked with a perfect alignment at the window sill and a resulting gap at the top, the prefered method of laying out the tile would be starting at the middle and working out. You should measure to be sure the tiles along the side of the window don't require a "sliver" to fill the gap.  Upon discovering that is the case, the starting point can be moved slightly left or right.
Your grid is a great plan, but as others have said, it will require quite a bit of luck to be achieved in a real application.

Thanks so much! I actually framed the walls and poured the floor myself and they're pretty precise. I'm going to fine tune it a bit when we put up the durock. My self leveling cabinet laser is easily my favorite tool. Can you elaborate a little more on what you mean by the "sliver" and the whole point surrounding that?

@JeremyP,  Sliver= very thin piece of tile.  Difficult to cut, to be thin.  However if you don't add the "Sliver" your grout line is thicker than the other lines. This makes the whole job look bad.  Plan to avoid this  scenario .  If you built everything super precise, this could all work for you.  Those of us that have done it a number of times, know to plan for things to not be so precise.  Good Luck.
